# Yup - Async validation after setTimeout

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik, yup

In order to save requisitions, the code below is using setTimeout after user enter a value. If a new one is entered, timeout is canceled.

I would like to confirm if the approach below is correct, since when the timeout is cleared, it does not return the Promise, as expected by async validation function "test".

```
let timeout = null;
const validationSchema = Yup.object({
  name: Yup.string("Enter your name").required("Name is required"),
    .test("checkDuplUsername", "Username already taken", function(value) {
      clearTimeout(timeout);
      if (!value) return true;

      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        timeout = setTimeout(async () => {

          let uname = value.trim().toLowerCase();
          let resp = await fetch('/check_username/' + value;

          resolve(resp.result.length === 0);
        }, 500);
      });
    })
})
```

Comment: For one, ```clearTimeout``` won't even have access to the timer to clear it since it's declared inside the scope of the Promise.

Comment: But it's working. You can check it on https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-example-vtj0l?fontsize=14 . The console.log("Here") only will be called once if you press keys quickly. If you remove clearTimeout, it will be called multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

You can use async validatation in the below manner after the timeout:

```
const validationSchema = Yup.object({
  name: Yup.string("Enter your name").required("Name is required")
  .test("checkDuplUsername", "Username already taken", function(value) {
    if (!value) {
      const isDuplicateExists = await checkDuplicate(value);
      console.log("isDuplicateExists = ", isDuplicateExists);
      return !isDuplicateExists;
    }
    // WHEN THE VALUE IS EMPTY RETURN `true` by default
    return true;
  }),
});

function checkDuplicate(valueToCheck) {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    let isDuplicateExists;

    setTimeout(() => {
      // CHECK HERE FOR DUPLICATE
      if (valueToCheck === "test") {
        isDuplicateExists = true;
        resolve(isDuplicateExists);
      } else {
        isDuplicateExists = false;
        resolve(isDuplicateExists);
      }
    }, 3000)
  });
}
```